# Dispose the commits without merge

Tags: git

I did git push wrongly from the another program.

Now I try to

```
git push origin master
```

from the correct position and commit.

However it says.

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first merge the remote changes (e.g.,
hint: 'git pull') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I understand the meaning of this message,

but I dont want to merge the last commit(because it was completely mistake!)

I want to overwrite the commits forcefully without git pull.

How can I make it ?

Comment: "I want to merge" and "I want to overwrite" are two different things.  Which one do you want?

Comment: its my typo,i Changed 'I dont want to merge'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `git push --force` to rewrite the history of the remote repo and extirpate the mistaken commit.
Beware that this will break anyone else who has pulled that commit.

Comment: oh,This is what I want to do.very simple thanks.I think the message should suggest to use '--force' option ...

Comment: @whitebear: No, because you usually _shouldn't_ use `--force`.